# Result functions of type x => x are unnecessary?

Tags: redux, reselect

There might be a gap in my understanding of how Reselect works.

If I understand it correctly the code beneath:

```
const getTemplates = (state) => state.templates.templates;

export const getTemplatesSelector = createSelector(
  [getTemplates],
  templates => templates
);
```

could just as well (or better), without loosing anything, be written as:

```
export const getTemplatesSelector = (state) => state.templates.templates;
```

The reason for this, if I understand it correctly, is that Reselect checks it's first argument and if it receives the **exact** same object as before it returns a cached output. It does not check for *value equality*.

Reselect will only run `templates => templates` when getTemplates returns a new object, that is when `state.templates.templates` references a new object.
The input in this case will be **exactly** the same as the input so no *caching functionality* is gained by using Reselect.

One can only gain performance from Reselect's caching-functionality when the function (in this case `templates => templates`) itself returns a new object, for example via .filter or .map or something similar. In this case though the object returned is the same, no changes are made and thus we gain nothing by Reselect's memoization.

Is there anything wrong with what I have written?
I mainly want to make sure that I correctly understand how Reselect works.

-- Edits --

I forgot to mention that what I wrote assumes that the object `state.templates.templates` immutably that is without mutation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, in your case `reselect` won't bring any benefit, since `getTemplates` is evaluated on each call.

The **2 most important scenarios** where `reselect` shines are:

- stabilizing the output of a selector when **result function** returns a new object (which you mentioned)
- improving selector's performance when **result function** is computationally expensive